# Why Muslims want to convert Non-Muslims to Islam?

Tags: conversion, religion

I just want to ask simple question that why Muslims want to convert other religion people to Islam? When god is one then what is the use of converting into Islam?

Comment: @goldPseudo I don't think "why one must believe in God?" is the same as "why Muslims proselytize?" If nothing else, the latter has historicity. Related, but not duplicates.

Comment: @Shoaib This post is asking two distinct questions: "Why do muslims want to convert..." and "What is the use of converting...", both of which are already asked and answered on the site. The second seems to be a clear duplicate of the post I linked, and I can't pick more than one "Duplicate" target.

Comment: @goldPseudo but the meaning of my question and the your link to duplicate question are different. But if you really think its duplicate then its okay.

Comment: I would recommend you take the time to focus your question better (see also "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)"); without details, it's pretty much impossible to understand any nuance to the question, or what will (or will not) actually answer it to your satisfaction.

Comment: @goldPseudo IMO, questions are duplicate when the same answer applies. My answer to this question (and some other answers), copy pasted in the linked question is a misfit.

Comment: There are other good questions of the same [type](http://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=proselytize)

Answer (score 2):

That is because Muslims believe that Allah sent the Islamic religion as the final religion, that it is obligatory for all human beings who hear of it to believe in. Your friend wants to save you from the hellfire. Also, besides the threat of the hellfire, Muslims just love Islam. We want others to experience the joy that we feel from this religion insha'Allah(God willing)

There are five verses of the Qur'an and one hadith (saying of the Prophet PBUH) that make it clear why we were created and how we must worship.

> It was reported from Abu Hurayra that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: "By the One in whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, not one of this nation, Jew or Christian, will hear of me and will die without having believed in that with which I have been sent, except that he will be one of the dwellers of Hell fire."

> And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. (Quran 51:56)

> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers. (Quran 3:85)

> This day have I perfected your religion for you, completed My favor upon you, and have chosen for you Islam as your way of life. (Quran 5:3)

> And We send not the Messengers but as givers of glad tidings and as warmers. So whosoever believes(in Islam) and does righteous good deeds, upon such shall come no fear, nor shall they grieve. (Quran 6:48-49)

> Allah forgiveth not that partners should be set up with Him(polytheism); but He forgiveth anything else, to whom He pleaseth; to set up partners with Allah is to devise a sin most heinous indeed. (Quran 4:48)

Answer (score 1):

Because Islam is the only religion that overcomes all other religions. It teaches a human being in each and every aspect of life. One of the most important fact of Islam is that Muslims have a Prophet Muhammad S.A.W whose life is a complete practical for every person to lead a successful life. The second one Islam has a Quran which is the most authenticated and most readable in the entire world.

Comment: **<comments deleted>**. Comments should primarily be used to ask for more information and suggest improvements. Not discussions. Take it [chat] if you want to do so.

Answer (score 1):

First, "Muslims want to convert" is bit of an overstatement, not substantiated by facts. Accept the euphemism "Muslims like to deliver the message." Even orientalists agree that there hasn't been organized converting - forcefully or otherwise - infidels to Islam, except possibly for Spain under Al-Mohavids. In fact, if you read Hans Kung, a Christian theologian and orientalist, he goes so far to say that Muslims rulers (especially those in Syria) "disliked" conversion to Islam, for political reasons.

Secondly, missionary works is a part of every religion, even secular religions like say liberal democracy. There is no guarantee that every missionary expedition has always remained faithful to the jurisdictions of delivering the message and the message alone. However, such transgressions (coercing people to change their faith) are not a norm. To judge of all Muslims by transgressions of a few zealots - speaking hypothetically - is unwarranted.

It is an oversimplification of any religion to reduce it into a matter of *identifying the right God.* Every religion has a worldview, even the godless religions. When Muslims preach, they speak not only of God but also of the Judgement - a worldview based on mankind subjected to a trial, the ephemeral nature of this world and the permanence of the next world. The question of how to spend ones ephemeral life is inextricably linked to the worldview. The answer in a nutshell is in following the Quran and the Sunnah. Taken this way, there is no place for religious relativism i.e. every religion is as every other religion.

Answer (score 1):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

You are confusing Invitation with Conversion. What utmost a Muslim can do is invite you to Islam. And if a non-muslim accepts the invitation, a Muslim can help him convert by *bearing witness to his acceptance of Islam* and *teaching him basic steps to be a Muslim.*

As far as I understand, A non-Muslim has to convert himself to a Muslim, Muslims can only Invite him and help him do it. This invitation is called Da'wah *(A mere translation of the word "invitation").*

The various campaigns of Da'wah you see are to invite people to Islam by showing them traits of truth and beauty of Islam. They help them realize the truth rather than forcing them to accept it. Moreover, forcing someone to accept Islam is unlawful in the Islamic law itself.

> #### [Qur'an :: Chapter 2 (Al-Baqarah) :: Ayah 256](http://quran.com/2/256)
>
> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.

Why are Muslims so interested in Da'wah?

At the primary level. A true Muslim is always a selfless person. He is a Da'ee (Promoter of Islam). He is convinced that the religion is the most truthful. He knows what a non-Muslim is deprived of and what he will go through if he doesn't accept Islam. This is why he wants all his fellow human beings to follow it.

@AmericanMuslim has a point here. Generally speaking, Every religion has Da'ees who promote their religion. They are somehow convinced that their own religion is most truthful.

Another point: Every child takes birth as a Muslim. Whether he is born in a Christian household or a Hindu family, he is born a Muslim. But his parents and caretakers make him a Christian, a Jew or other Non-Muslim.

> #### [Sunan Abu Dawud :: 1694](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/119)
>
> **Abu Hurairah reported the Messenger of Allah (May peace be upon him) as saying :**
>
> **Every child is born on Islam, but his parents make him a Jew and a Christian**, just as a beast is born whole. Do you find some among them (born) maimed? The people asked : Messenger of Allah! What do you think about the one who died while he was young? He replied : Allah knows best what he was going to do.

So, Inviting people to Islam is inviting people to their first and original religion.

The final verdict is:

> #### [Qur'an :: Chapter 3 (Aali 'Imran) :: Ayah 85](http://quran.com/3/85)
>
> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Comment: Now this answer make some sense that you just give invitation and if we accept it you will help us in that. But i have question you said every child is born as a muslim. what is the proof that the child is a muslim or hindu or christian or any other. what is the proof, is there any mark or something?

Comment: @CZAbhinav, Do you mean a birthmark? Even if it exists, every human being should have it in common because every person is born into Islam. So how will you distinguish people based on a mark that everyone'll have? As regards the proof, It is in the definition of the word Muslim (One who submits himself to God/Allah). Every born child submits himself/herself to the will of Allah and hence is a Muslim.

Comment: so this means I am also a muslim

Comment: @CZAbhinav, Let me reframe. **Every newly-born child is sinless and submits himself/herself to the will of Allah and hence is a Muslim until he is turned into a non-Muslim by his/her parents.** This means you were a Muslim when you were born. As you grew up, you were gradually converted into a non-Muslim by your caretakers.

Comment: I am actually really shocked after reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Because we muslim believe that islam is the right religion. It contains the right Beliefs like there is one God, Quran is God's message, Mohamed is God's prophet, there is paradaise and hell... It also contains statement of what God want us to do like from the birth to death like doing salat, zakat, siam.. So islam is about Beliefs and what human should do to make God satisfied. Other religion (even if they contain beleiving in god) have wrong Beliefs and wrong Acts of Worship. So trying to convert other to islam is trying to guide them to the right beliefs and the right way to pray to God so they can make God satisfied and as a result they win in this life and in the after life

Comment: **<comments deleted>**. Comments should primarily be used to ask for more information and suggest improvements. Not discussions. Take it [chat] if you want to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`why Muslims want to convert other religion people to Islam?`

Everyone, not just Muslims want people to convert to their religion. Christian, Jews, Scientology, etc.. all want people to join.

The question you should be asking is `why do people want people to convert to their religion?`. I answer that with the following reasoning:

- The more people like you are there are, the less you think of yourself as a minority.
- You get a sense of achievement.
- You get a sense that "my religion" is more right than other religions, thus making me look right.
- In many cases it is a empowering thing. The more people you have in your religion, the more access you have to money (Ex: Membership fees, donations) and voting power.

Going back to the original version, in Islam there is no Compulsion. Muslims shouldn't want to shove down Islam on other people, it is their actions that should speak for Islam and want people to convert to Islam oppose to forcing your ideas on others.

The best thing to do as a Muslim, act according to the Quran and Sunnah (as long as it does not contradict the Quran), which when people see will be effected and come asking you for Islam.

Forcing people into Islam never worked, look at most non Arabic countries where Islam was spread by the Sword (Europe, France, etc..) they easily reverted back to other religions once they were re-occupied by others.

Comment: What do you mean by "muslims shouldn't want to convert other people to islam"? Then what is daawa, and why did the prophet and his companions call out for people and invite them to become muslims if they shouldn't be wanting to convert people to Islam as you said?

Comment: @AbdelRahmanShamel Daawa by the prophet and companions was spread by their good words and actions, which is what I meant. I updated the answer.